# Change password through graph api disallows german umlauts

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I tried to change the users password through graph api to word containing german umlauts (e.g. <kbd>ä</kbd>, <kbd>ö</kbd>, <kbd>ü</kbd>, etc). But these passwords are rejected with error message :

> "Invalid format: Invalid characters in password"

Through graph explorer I call

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/
{
    "passwordProfile": {
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
        "password": "Valid2018"
    }
}
```

And it returns a `Success - Status Code 200`. But if I change the password to:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/
{
    "passwordProfile": {
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
        "password": "Gültig2018"
    }
}
```

I will get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid format: Invalid characters in password",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "...",
            "date": "..."
        },
        "details": [
            {
                "target": "password",
                "code": "GenericError"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So why are german umlauts forbidden in Graph API??

Comment: I guess they don't allow non-Latin characters?

Comment: Are there any possibilities to change this? Through password complexity rules you can change min and max length and if numbers only are allowed, but could you also allow non-Latin characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately,as juunas said that AAD doesn't allow non-Latin characters. For now, AAD Password policies that only allows following Characters:

> A – Z
>
> a - z
>
> 0 – 9
>
> @ # $ % ^ & * - _ ! + = [ ] { } | \ : ‘ , . ? / ` ~ “ ( ) ;

See more details about AAD Password policy in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-passwords-policy#password-policies-that-only-apply-to-cloud-user-accounts).